# Flush Postfix mail queue

Tags: rhel, email, postfix

I'm running an old version of Postix (1.1.7) on my Red Hat Linux and I wanted to flush the e-mails from a specific recipient with `postsuper`, which comes with the `postfix-perl-scripts` package. However, after some Googling, I realized that this package was released only for newer versions of Postfix. Maybe I'm wrong.

Any way to accomplish this task without `postsuper` ?

Answer (score 1):

I have Postfix 2.10 on CentOS 7, but I'm pretty sure you still want to run:

```
postqueue -f
```

to flush the Postfix [queue](http://www.postfix.org/postqueue.1.html).